# VBA function seems to return an array but I get "Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected"

Tags: arrays, vba

I have this set of VBA functions:

```
Sub x()
    Dim a() As Variant
    z y(a)
End Sub

Function y(a() As Variant) As Variant
    y = a
End Function

Function z(a() As Variant) As Variant
    z = a
End Function
```

When I run `x()`, the line `z y(a)` throws an error:

```
Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected
```

I guess this is happening because `z()` is expecting an array as an argument but the return value of `y()` is a variant, not an array.  I'm not sure how to make clear that `y()` returns an array of variants--did I declare it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your code does nothing, this will stop the error:

```
Sub x()
    Dim a() As Variant
    z y(a)
End Sub

Function y(a() As Variant) As Variant()
    y = a
End Function

Function z(a() As Variant) As Variant()
    z = a
End Function
```